# Flex CrossDomain.xml loading from adobe.com

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

In what scenario flex application tries to load the crossdomain file from this location:
http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml
As,i have placed the crossdomain at the root level of the server and from the browser i am also able to load it(if i hit root/crossdomain).Still it is pointing to the default adobe's.
Any Suggestions??

Comment: Do you have the framework set to be an RSL?  Flash Player /Flex may check for the cross domain before trying to downloading the framework SWZ files.

Comment: If Flextras' comment does not help try disabling loading stuff one-by-one until you find request that causes Adobe's `crolldomain.xml` to load.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.I am not using any RSLs framework.My only problem is why it is trying to fetch the crossdomain.xml from adobe.com.I know framework SWZs are loaded from there but not sure regarding the crossdomain.xml..My custom crossdomain.xml is placed at the root of my server also.I it not able to locate the custom crossdomain.xml on my server and then trying to fetch it from adobe.com???

Comment: hey, have solved this problem? can you help me, i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue. In settings for building your app (in Flash Builder-->Project-->properties) you need to add `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true` as a CLI argument.

This instructs to provide a few libraries on static linking and might increase the size of your swf, but the call to fpdownload.adobe.com/crossdomain.xml would stop.